# create image from data cocoa swift 5

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I have a set of Data coming from a request (AlamoFire) as per the image below:
[image]

I know it's an image, the size of the data is correct. I'd like to create an image from this and tried:

`NSImage(data: result)` or

`NSImage.init(data:result)`

Without success. It is possible to do what I try to achieve?

EDIT: to answer Larme on Self.coverImage:
[image]

Comment: The number of bytes looks good. What error do you get? Is the image `nil`?

Comment: Post a larger snippet, especially showing what exactly is `result` and how you're getting it.

Comment: Could you print the whole data? Using for instance `print("HexDataStr: \((result as? Data).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())`? Note, you could use a prefix, and print the first one only:  `print("HexDataStr: \((result as? Data)prefix(40).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())

Comment: What type of image is the source? It might not be natively supported by macOS

Comment: @vadian: no error, but just the image not appearing in its imageView

Comment: Please share the code how you add the image to its imageView.

Comment: If the data you get is simply a network call response, it could be anything. It can be an image data, it can be data for a String that is a Base64 encoded image data, it can be a JSON containing a Base64 encoded image data etc. You need to verify what is that even supposed to be.

Comment: @koen: NSImageView is an Outlet. Simply set the image of the imageView: CoverImageView.image = NSImage(data: result)

Comment: Are you updating your UI on the main thread?

Comment: Is `self.coverImage` nil in your breakpoint? Or is it setting the image to your ImageView that is causing the issue? You don't want to show the first bytes of your response?

Comment: @ koen: yes I do> @ Larme: self.coverImage is not nil. I'd like to print out the data, but got your suggestion not compiling

Comment: @koen: I might have been too tired. UI was not updated in the correct manner. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks to all. Got it working.

Answer (score -2):

This is a iOS snippet, if is useful for anyone:

```
// Swift
// Image to data
let image = UIImage(named: "sample")
let data = image?.pngData()
let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9)

// Data to Image
let uiImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

// this method is deprecated
var imageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Comment: Jajajaja! Undervote without reply :) the best action ever to help people.

Comment: I think you got the downvotes because the question is for macOS and your answer is for iOS.